# apt update keeps hanging, no way to troubleshoot

Tags: ubuntu, apt

Apt update on Ubuntu 16.04 hangs randomly every view updates.

Nothing I've tried can permanently fix it and I have no way to troubleshoot it.

The only solution I have is to create a shell script to `apt clean && apt update`. then it works.

`echo -e '#!/bin/bash\nsudo apt clean && sudo apt update' | sudo tee /usr/bin/apt-update; sudo chmod +x /usr/bin/apt-update`

Things I've done:

#### Switch to google DNS

Disable NetworkManager managed DNS

`sudo sed -i -e 's/^dns=dnsmasq/#dns=dnsmasq/' /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`

Add Google DNS to DHCP Client (dhcp will prepend google DNS to /etc/resolv.conf)

`echo 'prepend domain-name-servers 8.8.4.4;' | sudo tee -a /etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf`

`echo 'prepend domain-name-servers 8.8.8.8;' | sudo tee -a /etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf`

Restart NetworkManager

`systemctl restart NetworkManager.service`

#### edit apt config

Some repos have issues with http/1.1 pipelining.

Try the following:

`echo 'Acquire::http::Pipeline-Depth "0";' | sudo tee /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/99pipelining-off`

---

Sometimes its hard to see which repos are failing because of long timeouts

reduce the timeouts with

`echo 'Acquire::http::Timeout "5";' | sudo tee /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/99reduce-timeout`

---

Force IP V4 to disable attempting to resolve IP V6

`echo 'Acquire::ForceIPv4 "true";' | sudo tee /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/99force-ipv4`

#### create script for apt-update

Apt-get update often hangs/fails. the work around for this is to *always* `apt clean` before `apt update`

This command creates a script called `apt-update` that does just this and should be used instead of `apt-get update` or `apt update`

`echo -e '#!/bin/bash\nsudo apt clean && sudo apt update' | sudo tee /usr/bin/apt-update; sudo chmod +x  /usr/bin/apt-update`

#### enable automatic mirror switching

`sudo sed -i -e 's/deb http:\/\/il.archive.ubuntu.com\/ubuntu\//deb mirror:\/\/mirrors.ubuntu.com\/mirrors.txt/' sources.list`

enable partner repo

`sudo sed -i.bak "/^# deb .*partner/ s/^# //" /etc/apt/sources.list`

---

#### I tried editing the clean policy

`echo 'DSELECT::Clean "always";' | sudo tee /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/99DselectAlwaysClean`

`echo 'APT::Get::Clean=always;' | sudo tee /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/99AlwaysClean`

#### I even tried adding Post update and Pre update commands with

`echo 'APT::Update::Post-Invoke {"/usr/bin/apt apt clean || exit 0"};' | sudo tee /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/99PostUpdateClean`

`echo 'APT::Update::Pre-Invoke {"/usr/bin/apt clean || exit 0"};' | sudo tee /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/99PreUpdateClean`

these 2 commands are actually problematic because they seem to try to steal lock or something. In the end I deleted them.

### How can I permanently resolve this issue without resorting to hacks like a shell script that does `apt clean && apt update`?

### How can I troubleshoot this issue?

Comment: Are you sure the hang is unrelated to any external event? Did you check to see if there is a drop off or interruption in the bandwidth/connection and then a failure to reconnect?